# Downgrade Apple TV to 7.5

Tags: appletv

I've recently updated my Apple TV (3rd generation), model A1469, to 7.6 (8130). But now it freezes when pausing YouTube videos. Others have the same problem. Here are some reports and discussions:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251826984
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251813632
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251805180
- https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/72724736

How can I downgrade to 7.5? Can I download Apple TV software 7.5 from an official Apple server?

The instructions on the first link above point to https://ipsw.me/product/AppleTV, but this is not an official Apple site.

Comment: I've found https://www.iclarified.com/970/appletv-firmware-download-locations but it does not contain a link for 7.5.

Comment: [Apple TV Software Update 7.6.1](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202157) did not fix this problem.

Comment: [Apple TV Software Update 7.6.2](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202157) seems to have fixed this problem

Comment: Alas, YouTube no longer works in this Apple TV. Sad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've downloaded Apple TV software 7.5 from https://ipsw.me/download/AppleTV3,2/12H885 and the Finder info says it was downloaded from http://updates-http.cdn-apple.com/2020/ios/061-27784-20200313-6EA1D1F6-A6E5-40CB-8C61-B9680241903C/, which apparently is an Apple server.

Comment: I've yet to install 7.5. I'll post when I do.

Comment: See also https://tidbits.com/2020/09/28/third-generation-apple-tvs-suffering-from-apple-tv-software-update-7-6/

Comment: Since Apple TV Software Update 7.6.2 seems to have fixed this problem, there is no need to downgrade.